# Convergent sequence and adherent value "I'm right?"

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have this topology on $\mathbb{R}$ $$\tau = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}: \lfloor{x_0}\rfloor \notin A \lor A = \mathbb{R}\}$$

where $\lfloor.\rfloor$ is the floor function and $x_0>10$

I have two questions

1) Study the nature of the sequence $u_n=n$

---> I say, let $\ell\in \mathbb{R}$

- If $\ell=\lfloor{x_0}\rfloor$ then the smallest open set containing $\ell$ is $\mathbb{R}$ whicht contains all the sequence; then $\ell=\lfloor{x_0}\rfloor$ is a limit.
- if $\ell\neq \lfloor{x_0}\rfloor$ then the smallest open set containing 
  $\ell$ is $\{\ell\}$ which doesn't contain an infinite count the the sequence

Then the nature of $(u_n)$ is convergent to $\lfloor{x_0}\rfloor$

2) Give adherent value of the sequence $v_n=-n$

---> by the same way of the precedent question i found that $v_n$ converge to $\lfloor{x_0}\rfloor$ then the adherent value is $\lfloor{x_0}\rfloor$

Comment: Ah, I did not understand you meant the floor function before.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma i say to you in the comments

Comment: It doesn't really matter, as we still have the excluded point topology but with respect to a point in $\mathbb{N}$, so in my other answer I know that $x_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, which simplifies the answer a bit (no case distninguishing)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ok, and what do you think about my answer

Comment: Look at the continuity answer, it's simpler too.

Answer (score 0):

$\tau = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}: p \notin A \lor A = \mathbb{R}\}$, the excluded point topology w.r.t. some $p = \lfloor x_0 \rfloor  \in \mathbb{N}$.

Simpifying your argument slightly:

You rightly note that the only open neighbourhood of $p$ is $\mathbb{R}$. So trivially any sequence in the space converges to $p$ whatever the sequence is.

If $x \neq p$, then $\{x\}$ is open, as its complement contains $p$. This contains at most one element from the sequence so the sequence cannot converge to it. In fact the only sequences converging to $x$ can be those that are eventually constantly $x$ (and these still also converge to $p$, of course)

This applies to both sequences. They both have a unique limit namely $p$. 
Convergence is easy to reason about in this topology. All sequences converge (to $p$) and the eventually constant ones have 2 limits. That's all.

Comment: thank you so my answer is correct

Comment: @Vrouvrou yes, you are. But the write-up could be simpler, which is what I did.